# Understand Lambda-Expression in the context of linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

If i have the expression:

```
from p In Product Select p.Name
```

i understand that p is an Element of Products.

If i have:

```
Dim allProducts = Products.Select(Function(p) p.Name)
```

my question is how do i say here that p is an Element of Products?

Comment: There is no `k`. Only `p`.

Comment: corrected typing error sorry

Comment: @ruedi: The question is not clear. Basically there is no difference between `p` in the query syntax and `p` i the method syntax.

Comment: I just try to understand when i say p IN Product... i understand that p is an element of Product. As when i say for each x IN Y. But in the lambda Expression above p is also an element of Products but i just cannot see how this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the VB.NET compiler uses [Type inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163345.aspx)

Thanks to that, the types of the parameters and of the return value of the anonymous method `Function(p) p.Name` are discovered through the analysis of the signature of `.Select()` first (to discover the type of `p`) and then of the type of `p.Name` (to discover the return value type)

From [Basic Instincts: Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163362.aspx)

> The introduction of powerful type inference mechanisms means that you don't need to worry about figuring out the type of each variable.

and so on... It's quite long.

Comment: good explanation, i didnt get how the types are discovered, now i have it. helps a lot, thank u!